# Hosting multiple Java applications within a single JVM

Tags: jvm

What problem i'll face if i hosts multiple Java applications within a single JVM ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing this is that you do not benefit from the separation of address spaces and process contexts that you get from using separate JVMs. If one application thread terminates the application with an errant System.exit(0) or throws a fatal RuntimeException, all your applications will die. In addition, each application will share the same ClassLoader unless you explicitly force each to use a different ClassLoader.

Comment: Does each application get a separate JVM instance?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about JVM INSTANCE as when you say 'two instances of the same JVM'. It's usual to say instance of a JVM to a separate process, it is, to a loaded independent JVM.

Comment: It would be better to say that you could serve for example 10 webapps by the same Tomcat instance!!

Comment: Yes exactly i have 1 tomcat server and i want to host 3 web application. So will each application get a separate JVM instance ?

Comment: Generally speaking, each application will get its own JVM instance and its own OS-level process and each JVM instance is independent of each other.

Comment: You can refer also this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html . Hope it resolves your query!!!

Comment: Thanks for the ans. so if 1 application  thread terminates the application with an errant System.exit(0) or throws a fatal RuntimeException, all 3 application will die?